# Scroll to next div on body click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, scrollto

I have a number of divs all with the class '.slide' and a scroll to function that scrolls through them when a .slide div is clicked.

See here:
http://codepen.io/thomasjwpayne/pen/KFotg

However i'm trying to get the function to work when clicking on the body as opposed to the slide. Also because the slides are displayed as inline-block i need it to scroll to the slide after when the next slide is already fully in the viewport.

Does anyone have any direction on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to keep a tracker somewhere, in my example - I use the `body` to keep a `data-*` attribute which stores the current jQuery Object which is currently in view.

```
var currentSlide = $('body').data( 'current-slide', $('div.slide').eq(1) );
```

Then switch the `$.click()` handler from `$('div.slide')` to `$('body')`:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //get the current slide index from the body tag.
   $this = currentSlide.data( 'current-slide' );
   $next = $this.next('div.slide');

   if($next.length) {
        $next.scrollTo($next.attr('id'));
        //Save the next slide as the current.
        $('body').data( 'current-slide', $next );
   } else {
        //Throw us back to the top.
        $('div.slide:first').scrollTo($('div.slide:first').attr('id'));
        //Save the first slide as the first slide, which 
        //Cycles us back to the top.
        $('body').data( 'current-slide', $('div.slide:first'));
   }

   $(".slide a").click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

**CodePen Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tBqhJ

Comment: Thanks! This makes the body click work but still seems to have some problems when multiple slides sit in a row in the viewport. For example when i have a row of three slides the body then has to be clicked 3 times before progressing to the next row. I wondered if there's a way to get it to jump to the row below on a single click in these instances.

Comment: Certainly is! Exchange `$.click()` handler to step into `containers` rather than the `slides` themselves: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klICL

Comment: Ah sorry, i meant without restricting the width in a container. I'm trying to keep as many slides in a row as the browser width will allow.